# What is the artifact in NodeJs/Webpack project and how do we do CI/CD with that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, webpack, continuous-integration

I have a node js app that uses webpack, which basically builds all the files into a dist folder. What I want to do is automate the deployment process.

The thought process is:
1) Jenkins will pull the app from git 
2) Jenkins will build the app
3) Here is where I need help. The artifact in this case is the dist folder.

Most of the online examples have this where nodejs artifact is deployed into a nexus repository but in this particular case, do we need that. If not, how do we go ahead with deploying this built application?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus is a binary repository. It enables you to version your build artifacts. It's a good practice to version your build artifacts before deploying them, that way you can rollback in case there's an issue.

Deploying depends on your provider. If you just have a server you can access by ssh, there are several plugins to help you do that.

A popular one is https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps documentation at: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/#sshput-ssh-steps-sshput-put-a-filedirectory-on-remote-node

Comment: Ah ok, so in this case would it be a good idea for me to zip the dist folder and version it in nexus

Comment: Indeed it would. Unless your app is meant to be consumed by another app as a npm package. In that case instead of publishing to nexus, publish to npm (nexus can host npm repositories). A good practice then would be to deploy the artifact you versioned on nexus/npm. I mean instead of pushing your artifact from jenkins to your server (by scp for example), just fetch the artifact from nexus on the server (using wget for example, or npm)